# Using API Key on Site

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-services

I want to get numerical data with an API Key from a server to my website. I want to use that data, analyse it and show the results on my site. Which language do I have to know? Is Javascript enough?

Comment: Depends on your purpose. If you don't need to keep the analysis "secret" then I think JS would work fine. But since most of the time you want to keep your formulas and methods secret, then JS is not the tool

Answer (score 0):

I mean any coding language with the ability to perform a http request to the site containing the data, and then being able to manipulate the presumably json response would be enough. So yes, you can use javascript, you would presumably use something like Node for the back end server that sends the requests and does the data analysis and then some kind of front end framework like react or angular for the front end.

It really depends on your needs, but here are some potentially useful resources

[node](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_get_started.asp)

[http requests](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-build-rest-api-mobile-apps-using-node-js)

[getting started with javascript/web development](http://www.vikingcodeschool.com/web-development-basics)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use fetch. It is javascript. For example, to get data:

```
fetch(url, {
        method: 'get',
 })
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => {console.log(data)})
 .catch(exception => console.log(exception));
```

You can find for more details at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

You should try axios or jquery(ajax).